# How to solve Error comes in screen of ofbiz

Tags: tags, ofbiz

This is my code to Find records and show in list 
this give me error at tag .
how we can used screen with mandetory tag
how can i solve this problem?

```
    <screen name="searchTransactionScreen">
            <section>
                <actions>
                    <set field="headerItem" value="FindTransaction"/><!-- this highlights the selected menu-item with name "main"-->
                    <set field="titleProperty" value="PageTitleOfTransaction"/>
                    <set field="ofbizDemoCtx" from-field="parameters"/>

                </actions>
                <widgets>
                    <decorator-screen name="TerpCommonDecorator" location="${parameters.mainDecoratorLocation}">
                        <decorator-section name="body">

                          my search option section where i am includeing the menu and screeen
                            <decorator-section name="search-options">
                                    <include-menu location="component://terp/widget/TerpMenus.xml" name="AddDataMenu"/>
                                    <include-form name="FindTransaction" location="component://terp/widget/TerpScreens.xml"/>   
                            </decorator-section>
                            <decorator-section name="search-results">
                                    <include-form name="ListTransactions" location="component://terp/widget/TerpScreens.xml"/>
                            </decorator-section>

                           </decorator-section>
                  </decorator-screen>
            </widgets>
            </section>
        </screen>
```

please give me answer fast